# Returning an instance of a class giving error

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following code doesn't seem to work
The print statement is erroring out AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'week_num'

I'm attempting to add weeks to year-week input

```
class Week:
    def __init__(self, year, week_num):
        self.year = year
        self.week_num = week_num

    def isLeapYear (self, year) :
        if (year % 4) == 0: 
            if (year % 100) == 0: 
                if (year % 400) == 0: 
                    return True
                else: 
                    return False
            else: 
                return True
        else: 
            return False

    def maxWeeks (self, year) :
        if self.isLeapYear(year):
            return 53 
        else:
            return 52

    def plus (self, num) :
        def iter(week_num, year):
            max_week = self.maxWeeks(year)
            if(week_num > max_week) :
                return iter(week_num - max_week, year + 1)
            else :
                print(year, week_num)
                return Week(year, week_num)

        iter(self.week_num + num, self.year)


a = Week(2020, 8)
b = a.plus(13)
print(b.week_num, b.year)
```

Comment: My bad, I forgot to return  iter (switching between scala and python a lot)...But even if I return it, I get the same error. Added return the code

Comment: Nvm, I got what you were saying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`plus` doesn't return anything (technically it returns `None`). Therefore in `b = a.plus(13)`, `b` is `None`.